# Cannot escape path in bash file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run some command with looping through all files in a directory. The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
INPUT_DIR=$1
OUTPUT_DIR=$2

: ${INPUT_DIR:="."}
: ${OUTPUT_DIR:="."}

files="$INPUT_DIR/*.ttf"

for file in $files
do
    base_file=${file##*/}
    output="$OUTPUT_DIR/${base_file%.*}.woff"
    ttf2woff "$file" "$output" || exit 1
done
```

I'd expect the double qoutes around `$INPUT_DIR/*.ttf` would do the magic but apparently it's not:

```
$> ttf2woff_multi "/Users/ozan/Dropbox/Graphic Library/Google Fonts/fonts-master/ofl/raleway"
Can't open input file (/Users/ozan/Dropbox/Graphic)
```

and when I print out `$FILES` I get: `/Users/ozan/Dropbox/Graphic Library/Google`

What am I missing here?

---

Edit: `files="$INPUT_DIR"/*.ttf` instead of `files="$INPUT_DIR/*.ttf"` doesn't work either...

Comment: Quotes prevent [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to loop through a list of files, better store them in an array:

```
files=("$INPUT_DIR"/*.ttf)

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    base_file=${file##*/}
    output="$OUTPUT_DIR/${base_file%.*}.woff"
    ttf2woff "$file" "$output" || exit 1
done
```

Note you were saying `"$INPUT_DIR/*.ttf"` whereas I am suggesting `"$INPUT_DIR"/*.ttf`. This is to allow the globbing to behave as intended and expand properly.

---

The key point here, as Cyrus mentions in comments, is the fact of not quoting, since they prevent globbing.

See an example with some files.

```
$ ls f*
f1  f2  f3
```

Store with double quotes... it just matches the string itself:

```
$ files=("f*")
$ for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done
f*
```

See how it is expanded if we do not quote:

```
$ files=(f*)
$ for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done
f1
f2
f3
```

Comment: Makes sense, however when I echo $f I get:
"/Users/ozan/Dropbox/Graphic" and 
"Library/Google" in two separate lines.

Comment: @madpoet I don't know what does it mean: is this a directory, a file? Is this what you need?

Comment: Sorry it's hard to explain in comment since stackoverflow is stripping the newlines. The input directory ($INPUT_DIR) is "/Users/ozan/Dropbox/Graphic Library/Google Fonts/fonts-master". I'd expect all *.ttf files are echoed under that directory. However it prints out two strings "/Users/ozan/Dropbox/Graphic" and "Library/Google"

Comment: @madpoet ah, now I understand. Then you need to quote the directory but not the *: `files=("$INPUT_DIR"/*.ttf)`. I also edited my answer

Comment: Ok now I get it. In fact I knew quotes prevent globbing but I was confused when quoting only $INPUT_DIR didn't work either and it prints string in both cases so the answer is to use array...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the array solution, (which is a good solution), you can also make use of `read` with **process substitution**:

```
INPUT_DIR=${1:=.}
OUTPUT_DIR=${2:=.}

[ -d "$INPUT_DIR" -a -d "$OUTPUT_DIR" ] || {
    printf "error: invalid directory specified (INPUT_DIR or OUTPUT_DIR)\n"
    exit 1
}

while IFS= read -r file; do
    base_file=${file##*/}
    output="$OUTPUT_DIR/${base_file%.*}.woff"
    ttf2woff "$file" "$output" || exit 1
done < <(find "$INPUT_DIR" -type f -iname "*.ttf")
```

Comment: good one. Probably good to say `IFS=` in the `while` to "prevent trimming of leading and trailing whitespace" (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Thanks for more elegant solution. May I ask the reason for using "<" twice for the while loop?

Comment: That is what is called **process substitution** You are executing commands in a subshell `(find "$INPUT_DIR" -type f -iname "*.ttf")` and then the very specific `< <(foo)` is the syntax for redirecting the output of that process. Its is similar to **command substitution**, e.g. say `$(sed -e 's/foo/bar/' somefile)`, but instead of storing the output in a variable, you use the output as you would use `stdin`.